# IMAP in Corporate Gmail

Tags: python, gmail, gmail-imap, imaplib

I am trying to download emails using imaplib with Python. I have tested the script using my own email account, but I am having trouble doing it for my corporate gmail (I don't know how the corporate gmail works, but I go to gmail.companyname.com to sign in). When I try running the script with imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.companyname.com", 993), I get an error gaierror name or service not known. Does anybody know how to connect to a my company gmail with imaplib?

Answer (score 2):

IMAP server is still imap.gmail.com -- try with that?

Comment: what matti said. Just use your full email address as your username. (username@companydomain.com)

Comment: Ok, so I've done a little more poking around, and my company uses SSO, and from what I'm reading online imaplib does not play well with this. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're a domain admin you can use my library with a OAuth2 Service Account.  If you're an individual user, you might want to look at my code for the oAuth2WebServerFlow.  This should allow you to use OAuth (and not a password) to access GMail's IMAP.

https://github.com/richieforeman/oauth2gmail